# What is difference between $scope.$emit and $rootScope.$emit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, rootscope, emit

What is difference between $scope.$emit and $rootScope.$emit ?

I'm using it to emit from a directive to controller and it works un both ways!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785775/difference-between-scope-and-rootscope?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.$emit` allows the current scope and parents (including the rootScope) to listen for an event.

`$rootScope.$emit` allows only the rootScope to listen for a specific event.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.$emit` is useful when you want that `$scope` and all its parents and `$rootScope` able to hear the event. `$scope.$emit` is a child whining to their parents `$scope`.

And

`$rootScope.$emit` only lets other `$rootScope` listeners for catching it. This is useful  when you don't want to notify every `$scope`.

Answer (score -1):

`$emit()` sends changes to its parent scopes upward in the chain.

So, when you do `$scope.$emit`, you are sending a notification to the parent scope, which could be another `$scope` or might be `$rootScope`.
It basically works like `childScope > parentScope(s)`.

Its opposite is `.broadcast()`.

`.broadcast()` broadcasts changes to child scopes. So, if you broadcast from `$rootScope` then all the child `$scope`s listen.

---

#### From the docs:

> ### $emit(name, args);
>
> ***Dispatches an event `name` upwards through the scope hierarchy notifying the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners.***
>
> The event life cycle starts at the scope on which $emit was called. All listeners listening for name event on this scope get notified. Afterwards, the event traverses upwards toward the root scope and calls all registered listeners along the way. The event will stop propagating if one of the listeners cancels it.
>
> Any exception emitted from the listeners will be passed onto the $exceptionHandler service.

Comment: This does a good job of explaining what `$scope.$emit` is but not what `$rootScope.$emit` is. `$rootScope.$emit` will only let other `$rootScope` listeners catch it.

Comment: @ste2425 never thought of it before but it seems to be invalid.