# Why rootscope is used in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Why $rootscope is used in angularjs? can anyone tell the diffrence between scope and rootscope.

```
 $rootscope.mystr='';
```

Comment: The answer to this earlier SO question should help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785775/difference-between-scope-and-rootscope

Comment: Please refer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785775/difference-between-scope-and-rootscope

Answer (score 3):

“$rootScope” is a parent object of all “$scope” angular objects created in a web page.

[image]

$scope is created with `ng-controller` while #rootscope is created with `ng-app`.

[image]