# What is “$rootScope” and how is it related with “$scope”?

Tags: angularjs

I need complete explanation about Angular `$rootscope`. Sometimes I used Angular `$rootScope` but, I am not getting the values properly. Any one please help me to implement angular $rootscope.

Comment: Read documentation and do your research before asking a question. Some links: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785775/difference-between-scope-and-rootscope https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: For understanding the $rootscope and $scope, all you need is a perfect article. read this one http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/UVDE100914-Understanding-AngularJS-$rootScope-and-$scope.html

Cheers !