# Ng-show & ng-hide using $rootScope in my project?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code bellow and is working well, I would like to know how can make this variable show in my root-scope?

the problem is I am using now different controllers and directives 
so:

if I put this in  directive1:

```
<a href="" ng-click="showme=true">Show</a>
<button ng-click="showme=false">Hide</button>
```

and this in directive2 does not work:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
        <p ng-hide="showme">It will appear here!</p>
        <h2 ng-show="showme">This is mah content, yo!</h2>
      </div>
```

full code working if in the same directive html + angular

```
 <div ng-app="">
      <h1>Ng-show & ng-hide</h1>
      <p class="description">Click on the "show"-link to see the content.</p>
      <a href="" ng-click="showme=true">Show</a>
      <button ng-click="showme=false">Hide</button> 

      <div class="wrapper">
        <p ng-hide="showme">It will appear here!</p>
        <h2 ng-show="showme">This is mah content, yo!</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
```

I heard about I can use something like: `$rootScope` but how I can implement this in that case? thank you.

Comment: Make sure you define show on the $rootScope.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/31386649/5621827

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure `show` is set on the `$rootScope`. Convenient place for this is `run` block:

```
.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.show = false
}])
```

After that all scopes will inherit show from its parent.

Another option. You can actually directly refer to `$rootScope` from any of your template, this is probably simplest solution:

```
<a href="" ng-click="$root.show = true">Show</a>
<button ng-click="$root.show = false">Hide</button>
```

Comment: thanks my jshint complain about it:   20 |.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
         ^ Expected an identifier and instead saw '.'.
     20 |.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
         ^ Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
     20 |.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
          ^ Missing semicolon.
     20 |.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
          ^ 'run' is not defined.

Comment: Because it's not valid syntax. `.run` is a method of the angular module.