# $scope and $rootscope variables' life term

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angularjs, I see a lot of usages for $scope and $rootscope.
I like to understand the life term of variables attached to $scope and $rootscope.
Say, I have a.js/a.html and e.js/e.html.

a.js has $scope attached with variables say $scope.b, $scope.c, $scope.d for use in a.html.
If I load another page with e.js and e.html. Those $scope.b, $scope.c, $scope.d still have lives or they are removed. If I have $scope.b, $scope.c, $scope.d again in e.js, what could be issue?
I just want to highlight the life term of those attached variables.

Comment: My query is more on the life term of variables attached to $scope and $rootscope. Please look into responses, there is differences in emphasis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between $scope and $rootScope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785775/difference-between-scope-and-rootscope)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `$rootScope` - Usually configured in your main app.js file where you define your angular main module and main configuration. Even if not configured, it can always be injected.
2. `$scope` - your current scope in the current controller (page).

---

1. `$rootScope` variables live as long as you dont refresh your page. That means that they exist trough all transitions of your SPA.
2. `$scope` variables live only on the current scope (again, as long as you dont refresh the page) and they will get disposed once you transition to a different controller/page.

Comment: #1 is inaccurate...`$rootScope` is defined internally and always exists (within page life) , it's up to you if you want to inject it to access it

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for the clarification - edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

`$rootScope` lives as long as the whole page does

$scope instances are destroyed whenever the controller or directive using it are no longer active

No javascript is persistent between full page loads in browser

Answer (score 2):

`$rootScope` is global while `$scope` is local. When Controller is assigned to a page, so a `$scope` variable can be use here because it binds to this controller. But when we want to share its value across to other controllers or services, then `$rootScope` is being used (**there are alternative ways share values across but in this case we want to use `$rootScope`).

### [AngularJS Scope Life-Cycle](http://onehungrymind.com/notes-on-angularjs-scope-life-cycle/)

A property assigned with `$scope` cannot be used outside the controller in which it is defined whereas a property assigned with `$rootScope` can be used anywhere.

**Which means when you want variable witch can be use in single variable to use in multiple controller (whole application), you can use** `$rootscope`

> ### `$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil
>
> Scopes in Angular
>   form a hierarchy, prototypally inheriting from a root scope at the top
>   of the tree. Usually this can be ignored, since most views have a
>   controller, and therefore a scope, of their own.
>
> Occasionally
>   there are pieces of data that you want to make global to the whole
>   app. For these, you can inject `$rootScope` and set values on it like
>   any other scope. Since the scopes inherit from the root scope, these
>   values will be available to the expressions attached to directives
>   like `ng-show` just like values on your local `$scope`.
>
> Of course,
>   global state sucks and you should use `$rootScope` sparingly, like you
>   would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language. In
>   particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to put
>   a function on `$rootScope`, it's almost always better to put it in a
>   service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily
>   tested.
>
> Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in
>   life is to store and return bits of data.
>
> [— AngularJS Docs Miscellaneous - FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)

Comment: when you want variable which can be use in whole application is more appropriate to use a service, not $rootScope. Your bold statement is a poor practice

Comment: I just prefer $rootscope as single variable to use in multiple controllers, otherwise i also use services.

Comment: prefer and best practice are not the same though ... as noted in your yellow blockquote